# Unsure of Perl Datatype Referencing

Tags: perl, imap

I am trying to write a script using Net::IMAP::Client that outputs the body of a email, but so far every variable i try and output from the module shows up as something like: ARRAY(0x86f5524) or gives an error "Can't use an undefined value as a SCALAR reference."

The module documentation says that

```
# fetch full messages
my @msgs = $imap->get_rfc822_body([ @msg_ids ]);
print $$_ for (@msgs)
```

should contain references to a scalar. @msg_id should be an array of numbers for the email number in the inbox, but is also returned as an array reference.

I am unsure how to properly output this data so it is readable.
Here is the module reference: [Net::IMAP::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aIMAP%3a%3aClient)

and here is a snipit of my code:

```
use Net::IMAP::Client;
use Net::IMAP;
use Net::SMTP;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(
server => ,
user   => ,   # i omitted this data for privacy
pass   => ,
ssl    => ,
port   =>  ,
) or die "could not connect to IMAP server";

$imap->login or die('Login Failed: ' . $imap->last_error);

my $num_messages = $imap->select('[Gmail]/All Mail');

my @msg_id = $imap->search('ALL');
print @msg_id;
print "\n";

my @data = $imap->get_rfc822_body([@msg_id]);
print $$_ for (@data);
```

EDIT: I used Data::Dumper and got a big block of test containing the email and all the formatting tags. I also know that $imap-search should return something, as the inbox has 4 emails, 2 unread. But so since the variable @data IS holding the emails, i cant figure out the proper way to de-reference it in the output

Comment: print Data::Dumper( \@data ) will tell you what is in the return from $imap->get_rfc822_body([@msg_id]. Sounds like you're not getting anything back.

Comment: $imap->search can potentially return undef. So check to make sure you retrieved some data first.

Answer (score 5):

`$imap->search('ALL')` returns an **array reference** not an **array**. So you need to change

```
my @msg_id = $imap->search('ALL');
```

to

```
my @msg_id = @{$imap->search('ALL')};
```

It would be better though to check whether the method returned a defined value before dereferencing, in case it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, the proper usage is:

```
my $msgs = $imap->get_rfc822_body([ @msg_ids ]);
print $$_ for @$msgs;
```

---

The get the documented behaviour,

```
return $wants_many ? \@ret : $ret[0];
```

should be

```
return $wants_many ? (wantarray ? @ret : \@ret) : $ret[0];
```